# How to open link on iframe by on click random link?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to open a link on iframe when i click it from selected area (it mean link chatbot give link and open in iframe)

thinks will come link below.

from input button people ask for blog link.

then from bot give link like this-- > please viste: [www.bloglink.com](http://www.bloglink.com)
people click the link and link will open on ifram on same page top with 50%  height.

thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Iframe - Target for a Link</h2>

<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a" height="300px" width="100%" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>

<div class="wpaicg-chat-shortcode-type" style="background-color: black; color: #fff; height: 40px; width: 50%;">
    <span class="wpaicg-chat-message" id="wpaicg-chat-message">Sure, here's the link to the blog: <a href="bloglink.com" target="_blank">Here the blog link</a></span> <br/>
    <input type="text" class="wpaicg-chat-shortcode-typing" placeholder="Type a message" />
</div>

<p>When the target attribute of a link matches the name of an iframe, the link will open in the iframe.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try this with a real link, you will get errors unless both the page HOSTING this content is on the same domain as the link you click.  This is a security feature.

I modified your demo to try and load google below.  Check the dev console and you'll see this error:

```
refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.
```

```html
<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a" height="300px" width="100%" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>

<div class="wpaicg-chat-shortcode-type" style="background-color: black; color: #fff; height: 40px; width: 50%;">
    <span class="wpaicg-chat-message" id="wpaicg-chat-message">Sure, here's the link to the blog: <a href="http://google.com" target="iframe_a">Here the blog link</a></span> <br/>
    <input type="text" class="wpaicg-chat-shortcode-typing" placeholder="Type a message" />
</div>
```

So basically, unless you are loading content on the same domain, what you want to do is not possible.

Comment: understand but is it possible to show when iframe no have action, i mean empty data that time iframe show hidden, then when i click the link iframe will active and show the link.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but as long as you don't need to load a URL into an iframe you should be able to do whatever else you want with it

Comment: ok, i am getting one more problem with same code, onclick event are not working for mobile devices. after click it opens in new tab. any solutions here?